# Scanner requires two inputs before returning

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have some super simple code but I'm pulling my hair out. I'm just trying to have AskQuestion() return after the user gives one input but I don't understand why this java code requires 2 inputs before returning. Originally,  I was trying to solve this problem with a while loop, but I've deleted everything and found what I think the root problem is -- that a return only happens after a second input, but I cannot figure out why.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RelationalQuestion extends Question {
    RelationalQuestion(Animal[] animals, Animal answer) {
        super(animals, answer);
    }

    public boolean AskQuestion() {

        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean waitingForValidAnswer = true;
        boolean decideToDecrement = true;

        System.out.println("What do you want to know?");
        System.out.println("\t1. Is it heavier than another animal?");
        System.out.println("\t2. Is it taller than another animal?");
        System.out.println("\t9. Go back");

        if (q.hasNext());
            String relationalQuestionNumber = q.nextLine();

        return decideToDecrement;
    }// end AskQuestion
}// end RelationalQuestion
```

I don't think this affects this, but here's how I'm calling AskQuestion () from another file.

```
 if (input.equals("1")) {

        RelationalQuestion q1 = new RelationalQuestion (animalArray, answer);
        q1.AskQuestion();
        if (q1.AskQuestion() == false) {
        questionsLeft++; //neutalize decrement of questions if returned false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the ; after if.
Also you need an enter because you are doing readline . I just had 1 and then enter key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is showing two times the question due your code is calling AskQuestion() function twice.

```
q1.AskQuestion();                //call the first time the function
if (q1.AskQuestion() == false )  //call the second time the function
```

What I suggest is store the result into a new variable and compare after that.

```
Boolean result = q1.AskQuestion();
if(!result) { //.....// }
```

OR

Just delete the first call.

Comment: Thank you! Makes total sense. Don't know why I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    q1.AskQuestion();
>     if (q1.AskQuestion() == false) {
> ```

You are calling AskQuestion twice in a row. You should probably get rid of the first one.